# Ruby on Rails has_many DB Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, relationship

For suppose I have three database table eg:

users:

```
------------------------------------
user_id | name | email       |
------------------------------------
  1     | xyz  | x@gmail.com |
------------------------------------
```

companies:

```
------------------------------------
company_id | user_id | c_name |
------------------------------------
1          | 1       | abc    |
------------------------------------
```

posts:

```
------------------------------------
post_id | company_id | post_title |
------------------------------------
1       | 1          | etc        |
------------------------------------
```

This is my database.

Now I need at first I signup then create 1 or 2 or 3 companies into one
user_id then create post into company_id.

Now create company under user also create post but not update company_id in post table below my code:

user model:

```
  has_many :companies
```

company model:

```
has_many :posts, :foreign_key => :company_id
belongs_to :user
```

post model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :company
```

How can I reach this solution?

Thanks

Comment: It is still unclear to me what you are trying to achieve... On a sidenote: thanks for formatting the code this well ;)

Comment: You'll be better implementing something and seeing if it works

Comment: hi @thechamp, suppose for clearly understand I have created 3 companies which is company_id 1, 2 & 3, when I create post select company_id 2 then not update company_id 2 or anything  in posts table, hope will clear

Answer (score 0):

First, unless you have specific reasons not to use rails conventions, the primary keys in your tables should be called `id`, and not `post_id`, `company_id`, etc. This will happen automatically if you generate your models using rails generators (e.g. `rails g model user name email`, `rails g model company c_name user:references`, etc.)

Second, if I understand what you want to achieve, you should simply do:

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
  # Rest of your code
end
```

**Company model**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :user
  # Rest of your code
end
```

**Post model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  # Rest of your code
end
```

If you follow the standards, you don't need to specify any `:foreign_key`, which anyway was wrong in your code.

Comment: thanks your nice suggestion but I have already created big database & coding according to table id, now what to do I'm

Comment: In that case I'd suggest you study how ActiveRecord works first ([this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) is a good starting point), try to implement by yourself, and if you have specific problem you can ask here.